# Bigquery error "repeated values added outside of an array" even with value as array

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to save a RECORD mode REPEATED on BigQuery and I'm getting the error `repeated values added outside of an array`. I've seen two other questions here regarding this error. But they seem to be the case that the record was not being passed as an array, which is not my case. I have other fields RECORD mode REPEATED which work just fine following the same structure. It seems to be a bug on BigQuery.

The schema I used to create the table:

```
[
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "id",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "date",
        "type": "DATETIME"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "config_onboarding",
    "type": "RECORD"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "date_insert",
    "type": "DATETIME"
  },
  {
    "fields": [
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "key",
        "type": "STRING"
      },
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE",
        "name": "value",
        "type": "STRING"
      }
    ],
    "mode": "REPEATED",
    "name": "features",
    "type": "RECORD"
  }
]
```

When I run the code to insert with only the `config_onboarding` field it works:

```
self._client.insert_rows(
    table=table,
    rows=[
        {
            'config_onboarding': [
                {'id': 'template-install', 'date': '2021-07-01 18:43:44.810000'}, 
                {'id': 'run-workflow', 'date': '2021-07-01 18:43:44.810000'}, 
                {'id': 'template-workflow-view', 'date': '2021-07-01 18:43:44.810000'}, 
                {'id': 'automate-workflow-wrapper', 'date': '2021-07-01 19:50:00.901000'}, 
                {'id': 'share-workflow', 'date': '2021-07-01 19:50:00.901000'}
            ],
            'date_insert': datetime.now()
        }
    ],
    selected_fields=self._schema,
    ignore_unknown_values=True,
    skip_invalid_rows=True
)
```

The result is an empty array meaning there were no errors. Also I can check the entry was added by querying the table.

But when I add the `features` field which follows the exact same structure, it fails returning an array with errors saying `"repeated values added outside of an array"`:

```
self._client.insert_rows(
    table=table,
    rows=[
        {
            'config_onboarding': [
                {'id': 'template-install', 'date': '2021-07-01 18:43:44.810000'}, 
                {'id': 'run-workflow', 'date': '2021-07-01 18:43:44.810000'}, 
                {'id': 'template-workflow-view', 'date': '2021-07-01 18:43:44.810000'}, 
                {'id': 'automate-workflow-wrapper', 'date': '2021-07-01 19:50:00.901000'}, 
                {'id': 'share-workflow', 'date': '2021-07-01 19:50:00.901000'}
            ], 
            'features': [
                {'key': 'foo', 'value': 'bar'}, 
                {'key': 'hello', 'value': 'World'}
            ], 
            'date_insert': datetime.now()
        }
    ],
    selected_fields=self._schema,
    ignore_unknown_values=True,
    skip_invalid_rows=True
)
```

Do you guys have any clue?

## UPDATE:

It turned out that It was missing the schema definition for the `features` field on the schema parameter. That was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As per the table schema you have provided, I tried from my end.

[image]

You can try the below code to insert values into the table based on your schema.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of table to append to.
table_id = "ProjectId.DatasetId.TableId"

rows_to_insert = [
    {"config_onboarding":[{"id":"template-install","date":"2021-07-01 18:43:44.810000"}],
      "date_insert":"2021-07-02 18:43:44.810000",
      "features":[{"key":"abcd","value":"hundred"}]},
]

errors = client.insert_rows_json(table_id, rows_to_insert)  # Make an API request.
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
else:
    print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I managed to fin the issue. It was missing the schema definition for the `features` field on the schema parameter.